# How to edit an existing PDF(Created using Acrobat pro) on iPad PhoneGap application

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, cordova

We developed a phoneGap application running on iPad, which is having multiple PDFs(created using acrobat pro or some other softwares).

We need to edit input fields(of multiple types) in a pdf on "iPad" hybrid application and save the same.

Please suggest how this can be done on iPad hybrid app based on phoneGap framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin we just released which works with the open source library ILPDFKit (https://github.com/InformationArchiTECH/ILPDFKit-Cordova-Plugin).  The only downside we've found is this only works for a range of PDF's.  1.4 and earlier seems to work fine.  You can downgrade PDF's using this tool: http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html.